# Get all names in a HTML string PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter, explode

I got a string that contains HTML and I want to get the names so that I'll store it in the database.

Example

`$string1` would be:

```
<input name="text1"><input name="text2_new">
```

It's hard to determine since name the name doesn't have the same texts or the same length.

Comment: So what have you tried? What problems are you having?  Have you looked into using a DOM parser?

Comment: You'll have to use a regular expression or other methods

Comment: No regular expressions plz. Use an `HTML DOM` parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with a [DOM Parser](http://php.net/dom).

- Load the HTML string using [`loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method
- Find all `<input>` tags using [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method
- Get the `name` attribute using [`getAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) method and echo it

Code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('input') as $tag) {
    echo $tag->getAttribute('name')."\n";
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/51700)